# replace literal value by variable in for loop

Tags: python, mongodb

I have this code that works as expected. "db" is MongoClient object.

```
collections = {
    "cmrb": cmrb,
    "rbss": rbss,
    "ndrb": ndrb,
    "nder": nder,
    "rbph": rbph,
    "rb90": rb90,
    "rbphne": rbphne,
    "dirb": dirb,
}

c=db.cmrb
c.insert_one(collections['cmrb'])
```

But when I replace the collection name with variable i using for loop, all the entries gets added to collection "i" and not to "cmrb", "rbss" etc.

```
for i in collections.keys():
    c = db.i
    c.insert_one(collections[i])
```

What is wrong with the code mentioned above? How do I replace the literal "i"?

Comment: What are the values in your dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `MongoClient` is assuming `i` as a name of collection, in this case you have to use indexing operator to access the collection.

Replace:

```
for i in collections.keys():
    c = db.i
    c.insert_one(collections[i])
```

**With:**

```
for i in collections.keys():
    c = db[i]
    c.insert_one(collections[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
for i in collections.keys():
    c = db[i]
    c.insert_one(collections[i])
```

the `i` in `db.i` does not refer to the `i` in the for loop. `db.i` will simply create (in first iteration) or get(in other iterations) a database/collection named `i`. From the docs:

> **db[collection_name] || db.collection_name** Get the *collection_name* Collection of Database db.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to access an object attribute by string, use `getattr()`:

```py
for name, value in collections.items():
    c = getattr(db, name)
    c.insert_one(value)
```